# C# Streamwriter help

Tags: c#

Hey guys I need a tad bit of help.  I need my streamwriter to right out the file names i get from a Directory.Getfiles call

```
string lines = (listBox1.Items.ToString());
        string sourcefolder1 = textBox1.Text;
        string destinationfolder = (@"C:\annqcfiles");
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcefolder1, lines + "*.ann");
        foreach (string listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
        {
         Directory.GetFiles(sourcefolder1, listBoxItem + "*.txt");
         StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(destinationfolder + "\\" + listBoxItem + ".txt");
        }
```

It creates the files perfectly it just doesnt add any content to the files.  All i really want is the filename of the files it finds in the getfiles result.

Thanks in for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    foreach (string listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
    {
     using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(destinationfolder + "\\" + listBoxItem + ".txt"))
     {
           foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(sourcefolder1, listBoxItem + "*.txt"))
           {
                 output.WriteLine(fileName);
           }
     }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for using using.  I don't understand why this is not used in more examples, and by more people.  I know I'm not a C# pro, but it just seems like this is a good way to not forget closing and disposing things.

Comment: Tester101, int the File.WriteAllxxx() the using is built-in

Answer (score 2):

Since `GetFiles` returns a `string[]`, don't use `StreamWriter` *at all* - just

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, files);
```

Where `files` is the `string[]` of paths to write, and `path` is the destination file.

Comment: this would be perfect except i only want the file name

Comment: when i write out the result to the textfile it has the full path + file name, all i wanted was the filename

Comment: this is perfect, but how can i i remove the file path from the string path

Answer (score 1):

Two things. Firstly you actually need to write the data to the StreamWriter, and secondly you need to make sure you close the StreamWriter so it actually gets flushed to the file.

Try this:

```
foreach (string listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
{
    String[] filesInFolder Directory.GetFiles(sourcefolder1, listBoxItem + "*.txt");

    using(StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(destinationfolder + "\\" + listBoxItem + ".txt"))
    {
        foreach(string filename in filesInFolder)
        {
            output.Write(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

The `using` statement ensures that the StreamWriter is closed when the execution passes out of the using block.

Alternatively, if this is all you are writing to the file, you could take a look at the [Files.WriteAllLines(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your `StreamWriter.`

Or wrap your StreamWriter in a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement, this will dispose and close your stream automatically.
The reason behind this is that your stream will keep your output in a buffer and only write it to a file when:
- a certain threshold is reached
- you call flush on it explicitly
- close or dispose the stream

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your streamwriter in a using statement, which will flush and close the streamwriter

```
using(StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(destinationfolder + "\\" + listBoxItem + ".txt"))
{
    //Any code that writes in output
}
```